# org-mode agenda view by headline

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have several agenda files, many of which have an "ideas" top-level subtree.  I'd love a collapsable, editable view that shows each of these subtrees in a single buffer (though it wouldn't correspond to any single file).  I understand I can do an agenda keyword search for "*ideas", but that just gives me a list of the subtrees, while I then have to tab through each one to a different buffer.  Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: How about an `idea` tag or an `idea` property drawer for all the subtrees and then `org-tags-view` gets them all?  `org-search-view` would also suffice, but not necessarily be limited to tags and/or property drawers.  In terms of collapsing, that would most likely be a custom feature that needs to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using org-search view now, but I want a single, editable view, rather than having to tab through.

Comment: The agenda buffer is a *copy and paste* from the master todo files (not the whole entry(ies), just a select portion) -- when editing, the user is actually jumping back to the original to make the edits, and then the agenda buffer regenerates a new *copy and paste* from the original master(s).

Comment: I wonder if something like occur-edit-mode could serve as inspiration for such an implementation.